# Databricks: how to get the data behind the workflow information page exported

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I would like to export all the handy data held on the databricks workflows tab shown here[image: lovely workflow info]

as a csv or anything really so I can use the data elsewhere. How do I go about that? NB I've tried just copy and pasting it as a last resort but it doesn't even do that well (one column of rubbish) so if can be done programmatically that would be great. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of achieving it:

- One way is to use [List jobs command of Jobs REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsList) as it mentioned by Ganesh - you can use whatever language you want to implement it, but you need to handle output correctly as there could be multiple pages of data.
- Another way is to use [jobs command of databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/jobs-cli.html). The `jobs list` command has command-line parameter `--all` to get all defined jobs at once, and it also allows to get output as JSON, so you can use tool like `jq` to format it as you want (you must use `--version 2.1` flag because this command requires API 2.1):

```bash
databricks jobs list --all --output JSON --version 2.1
```

P.S. If you need more detailed information, pass `--expand-tasks` parameter - it will output information about tasks inside jobs